# In-memory document storage in Vespa.ai

Tags: vespa

Is there any way to store document data in-memory rather than on disk? This way the performance can be increased because of reduced IO.

Answer (score 4):

You can either use `attribute` fields in combination with `fast-search` (to build posting lists on top of the data), or consider putting the index on RAM-disks. The most common approach is to use a combination of `attribute` fields and on-disk index and use SSD drives, though.

Also, for `document summaries` it is good for performance to have all fields in the most commonly requested summary class be `attribute` fields.

Comment: Note also that Vespa will automatically use free memory to cache disk data.